# How to optimize query to avoid timeout on mysql/php connection

Tags: php, mysql

I recently design a php/mysql website.

I the index page I used this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM upload WHERE aid = '206' AND pin = '0' AND format like '%video%' ORDER BY created DESC

SELECT * FROM upload WHERE aid = '206' AND pin = '0' AND format like '%image%' ORDER BY created DESC    

SELECT * FROM upload WHERE aid = '206' AND pin = '0' AND format like '%image%' ORDER BY created DESC
```

I do not have a big data yet...maybe 1000 records in DB.

But when I load the page..it takes 8-20 seconds to load.

when I remove that sal queries,the load time will be normal.

please advice me best method to resolve that.

Comment: Is your database hosted remotely or locally

Comment: locally,also I only can use localhost as host,not 127.0.0.1...

Comment: Why are you second and third query equal?

Comment: Use indexes on your table.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 3 different SQL queries to get the data from same table.

You can get the same result using only one SQL query.

So SQL query should be as below.

```
SELECT * FROM `upload` WHERE `aid` = '206' AND `pin` = '0' AND (`format` like '%video%' OR `format` like '%image%') ORDER BY `created` DESC
```

---

There may be chances that you might have included many CSS,Images or JavaScript libraries.

You can check your page performance issue using below site.

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

Answer (score 0):

Things that might be worth trying to speed things up:

- add appropriate indexes to your table (perhaps `aid` should be an index?)
- combine these three queries into a single query (as per Ali Khanusiya's answer)
- add an appropriate `LIMIT` clause to your query (eg. `LIMIT 1` or `LIMIT 10`) to fetch a subset of the results (you can use an `OFFSET` to paginate the results)